# Why does this output end in two empty lists?

Tags: python, csv, iteration

```
import csv

f = open('biltins.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    print row

f.close()
```

When I run this code it ends with not one but two empty lists. How do I eliminate the two pointless lists?

Comment: Remove the blank lines at the end of the file? Check `if row:` before `print`ing it?

Comment: What is the contents of your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have some whitespace in your file.

Just say:

```
for row in csv_f:
    if row: 
        print row
```